# Shared consciousness or dream story

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a story when I was younger about a group of people who found themselves on the run, being pursued by "shadowy figures".

In the end it was revealed that they had all shared the same consciousness or "dream" while unconscious, and the shadowy figures were the doctors trying to help them.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: It sounds like a typical Dean Koontz story. The only thing missing is an over intelligent pet

Comment: If it's Koontz, it could be 'Strangers'.

Comment: It wasn't Koontz, but thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this one is what you're looking for, but I read books of Rainer Wekwerth, which have a similar content. In those books the characters go through different worlds and in every world one person can't go on into the next, and only the one person, who survives all the worlds can awake at the end.

In German the first book of the series is called "[Das Labyrinth erwacht](https://www.amazon.de/Das-Labyrinth-erwacht-Rainer-Wekwerth/dp/3401067885)", but I can't find the english title at the moment, sorry.

Comment: It doesn't appear that these books have been translated into English, hence there's no English title (although it would be "*The Labyrinth Awakes*")

Comment: @Valorum we're not sure OP read it in English, though?

Comment: Indeed. Given the paucity of information in the question, we're not sure that it's even a prose story

Comment: Thank you definitely a piece of prose, and definitely in english.